# SQL Server Agent Jobs Run Successfully but Output No Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ssms

Recently I was tasked to move two of our SQL Server Agent Jobs from one server to another as the old server is getting retired. These jobs run perfectly on the old server. Keep in mind I was not the one who created the SSIS packages that these jobs use. I also consider myself to have basic knowledge of SSIS.

I don't have permission to manipulate our servers so I had to work with our IT department to get this work done. I sent the IT department the two .dtsx files for the packages and they setup copies of the two jobs on the new server.

When I run these two jobs on the new server, they complete successfully but they run very quickly (compared to the old server's jobs) and I notice while looking in the message logs that they're writing 0 rows to my Excel output files.

There are no errors or even warnings that differ from the message logs I see for them on the old server where they're working perfectly so I'm at a loss for what's going on. I'm assuming I missed something very obvious like having to modify the jobs in Visual Studio in some way to account for what server they actually live on as I literally sent the same exact .dtsx files that are used on the old server (I was assuming what server the jobs live on doesn't matter from the SSIS/Visual Studio perspective because they don't pull any data from either one).

Anyway I'm just spitballing what the problem might be. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are there any connection setting that need to be configured in the SSIS portion on SSMS? I know for some of our packages if we don’t configure the settings after the project is deployed the first time they act very differently

Comment: It's possible. I will bring that up to IT for them to investigate. The problem is I can't actually see those settings in SSMS myself because I'm not an admin.

Comment: Are these packages deployed to the Integration Services Catalog?  If not - then how are they deployed to the new server?  Who sets up the agent jobs - and are those set with the correct parameters for the packages?

Comment: Yes, they are deployed to the Integration Services Catalog just like they are on the old server. I checked the parameters for the agent jobs and they are exactly the same as on the old server as well.